# loop a list - length of list but do not need the item created, pythonic?

Tags: python, python-3.6

This is going to be a bit silly of a question.  I have a simple list:

```
my_list = ["apple", "orange", "car"]
```

And I'd like to run a loop for the length of that list, but I don't need anything in the list.  I can clearly do this:

```
for item in my_list:
    call_external_thingy()
```

Which would loop 3 times, perfect.  However, I'm never using the `item` in my for loop.  So while this does work, everytime I look at my code I feel that I've made a mistake, "Oh shoot, I didn't pass `item` in.. oh right I just need to run that command for the number of items in the list..."

What would be the more pythonic way to simply run a for loop for the number of items in a list without creating `item`.  I'm thinking of something with `len` or `range` but can't get my head around it and anything I mock up just looks like a big mess.

Note, I'm tempted to put this on codereview instead, but they usually want *all* the code and a lot of why.  This seems like a simple enough question to be here, but I could be wrong!

Thank you!

Comment: Good dupe find!  I was searching around quite a bit before posting, but it makes sense that somebody else already asked this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pythonic :

```
for _ in my_list:
    call_external_thingy()
```

Comment: Interesting!  Does the `_` have a special meaning?

Comment: it's just like any other variable. you can use it like item but it doesn't stand out too much

Comment: _ has different purposes in python. https://hackernoon.com/understanding-the-underscore-of-python-309d1a029edc explains some _ usages

Comment: isn't it better to loop through a generator though? arent those genraly faster

Comment: @sniperd in this context it's generally understood as a value that has no significance in what you're doing (EDIT: that's in reference to your first comment)

Comment: @sniperd  It's just a convention to use `_` to explicitly indicate that you aren't going to use the loop variable. However, in some contexts `_` does have other meanings.

Comment: @JonasWolff Nope, why make a generator when you already have a list?

Comment: Thank you all for the great links and input, this is a great answer and very helpful comments.  I didn't know of the `_` convention as a throw-a-way (for lack of a better term).  Wonderful!

Comment: @sniperd Sometimes, especially in comprehensions, you see code where `_` is used as a loop variable which then *does* go on to use `_`. But such code is evil! ;)

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    call_external_thingy()
```

Comment: You don't need the `0` in the first argument of range, since it will default the starting point to be `0`.